# Implementing onclick listener for app widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an app widget which displays some rss feeds.It contains a text view which will display news title and an image view to diplay image.In that widget I want to add two buttons which function as next and previous to navigate through news titles.I know how to do this in an activity but how can I implement onclick listener for these buttons in widget

Here is my xml=>

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/titlebg2" />
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/foot" />
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/img" />
<Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/up" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/up"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/up"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#ffff" />
      <Button
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/up"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/down" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Follwing is my onupdate function,
=>

```
 public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )
        {

         parse();//Here Iam parsing the xml
         RemoteViews remoteViews;
             ComponentName watchWidget;


            remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main );
            watchWidget = new ComponentName( context, madhyamambig.class );

            remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.title, Title[0]);


            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(image[0]).getContent());


                 remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView4, bitmap);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( watchWidget, remoteViews );

        }
```

On an activity, we can simply do this like,

```
     int i=0;
      next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


 Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new      URL(image[i+1]).getContent());


                     remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView4, bitmap);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( watchWidget, remoteViews );

            }
          }


        });
```

I want to implement the same in widget.Somebody please help me...Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method.

Then launch a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) that will be caught by a service, a broadcast receiver or a service. The context targeted by this intent will be able to manipulate the source widget by using RemoteViews again.

Click processing is a bit more complicated as everything that is a stake here is to manipulate UI elements in a remote process.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help.Since iam a starter can you please be more descriptive??..

Comment: That's not the way it works on SOF. You come here with a question, your code and precise problems. Then people comment, but no one codes for you here. Did you try to google  RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent to get started, find some code snippet and see where you get into troubles ?